# Adding textview dynamically to table layout

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

Hi below is my code for the front end and backend. What I'm trying to do is add a textview and a row to the table layout portion of the xml dynamically. Does anyone see anything wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relLayout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Enter Stock to Add" android:textSize="15px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20px" android:layout_marginRight="20px" android:layout_marginTop="20px"></EditText>
    <Button android:id="@+id/addButton" android:layout_width="100px" 
            android:layout_below="@id/editText1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Add Stock" android:layout_marginRight="20px" android:textSize="15px"></Button>

</RelativeLayout>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

</TableLayout>
```

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("This is text");

    tl.addView(row);
    row.addView(tv);
    //set the layout of the view
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: You didn't really describe what is _the problem_, why do you think there is something wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you try to call setContentView(R.layout.main); before you add the new element?

Comment: i guess the setContentView call will generate the layout elements from the xml description. So when you modify elements before that these modifications will be lost. But thats just my guess.